# Assign Button Click to ctrl+F in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to assign ctrl + F to a search button so when I click it it will open the search box on a pdf which I had added to a WPF userControl in a WebBrowser.

> My code is based on something I have seen here on another post but doesn't work and gives me an error on the webBrowser.Focus method:

```
System.ExecutionEngineException
  HResult=0x80131506
  Message=Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown.
```

This is what I have now:

XAML:

```
<WebBrowser  x:Name="webBrowser" Source="file:C:\myFile.pdf" />
```

CS:

```
 private void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser.Focus();
            SendKeys.SendWait("^(f)");
        }
```

Please if you have any ideas or alternatives to do this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: deleted my answer, as what you try to do is prevent using of keyboard, I think you may specify it in the answer.

Comment: In fact, you don't want to assign ctrl+F to the button, but you want to assign the button to ctrl+f (exactly the opposite thing). I made a quick search, but unfortunately didn't find anything that would help.

Answer (score 0):

I found interesting thing on [github](https://gist.github.com/DrustZ/640912b9d5cb745a3a56971c9bd58ac7). I tested it, and it works for a desktop application.

May be tested for web applications.

The main function that interests you is `SendKeyboardInput`.